# What can I do to stop a character's movement upon hitting an object?

Tags: actionscript-3

I want my controlled character to completely stop moving when he hits a specific object (and not regain control until he answers the question correctly.) But I can't seem to figure out how to make him stop and remove control from the user, removing the key functions that allow character movement only works for the first instance of this and afterwards only stops the character if he falls onto the object rather than touch it (basically keeps moving the character if he touches the object horizontally in every instance afterwards). The current code for the hitTest is below if it helps.

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, information);
function information(e:Event)
{
if (player.hitTestObject(folder))
{
    removeChild(folder);
    myInfo.alpha=100;
    myInfo.gotoAndStop("folder1");
    myInfo.x=player.x;
    myInfo.y=player.y-50;
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,kU);
    //stops player movement
    myInfo.myA.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, answerA);
    function answerA(event:MouseEvent)
    {
    trace("answer A");
    myInfo.alpha=0;
    stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, kU);
    }
```

the "kU" function is the function that checks whether a key is not being pressed and doesn't seem to work when i switch it with the "key down function" I have. the code for movement is below.

```
function loop(e:Event)
{
if (kLeft) 
{
    speedX=-15;
}
if (kRight)
{
    speedX=15;
} 
else 
{
    speedX*=0.5;    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nullifying the "kLeft" variable and the "kRight" variable effectively stops the character upon the hitTest. The reason nothing else would work is because the Movement is in a seperate function than the hitTest (so i guess it would constantly detect movement and count that instead). Anyways, the code i used was

```
kLeft = null;
kRight = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a boolean value and set it to true when the object hits  the specific object you want , then if the boolean value is true you disable the movement code , but when it becomes say false you can activate it again ...

So basically the movement code depends on the boolean value ...

Regards

Comment: I attempted to do that but it wouldn't work out because the hitTest and the movement were in different functions (and i didn't want to redo the entire code :b) But i did figure out how to stop them. What i did was nullify the key movement variables so that they wouldn't register, makes me feel kind of stupid now that it took me so long to figure out. Thanks anyways for your help!